# Limit number of request per unit of time

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In spring MVC or security is it possible to limit number of request per unit of time e.g 2 search request per second.

I want to avoid malicious request.

Answer (score 2):

Request throttling is typically configured in application server/container or reverse proxy/load balancer. Also some ESB and integration products (like Mule and Camel) have relevant features.

To my knowledge neither Spring MVC nor Spring Security have any capabilities allowing limiting of request amounts, apart from possibility to limit number of concurrent authenticated sessions for a single user inside Spring Security.